# adding exponents with unknowns with the same base

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you add numbers with the same base but with unknown exponents? For example, $2^{x+2} + 2^{x+2}$ I understand that you do $2^x \cdot 2^2$ but I get stuck here. I don't know what to do from here or where to get the working out for the next step.

Thanks

Comment: Is that $2^{x+2}$ or $2^x + 2$?

Comment: @Ben Grossmann the first one.

Comment: So in general if you want to calculate
$$
n^a + n^b
$$
there is no simplified form for this. It's only if you have **multiplication** that you can simplify these, for example
$$
n^a \cdot n^b
$$
This you could simplify to $n^{a+b}$.

Answer (score 1):

An expression of the form  $ a^n + a^m $  is already in simplest form.

You may, however, if you wish: decrement an exponent by factoring out an $a$ from the term, or increment an exponent by factoring out $\frac1 a$ from the term. That is, the above expression can be written equivalently as any of the following:

$ (a)(a^{(n-1)}) + (a)(a^{(m-1)}) $

$\frac{a^{(n+1)}} {a} + \bigl( \frac{1} {a} \bigr)(a^{(m+1)})$

$ $
By factoring out $a$ or $\frac1 a$ more than once, you can write the equation as:

$ (a^3)(a^{(n-3)}) + \bigl( \frac {a^{(m+5)})} {a^5}  \bigr) $

which we can tell is equivalent to the original expression by using exponent rules:
$  (a^3)(a^{(n-3)}) + \bigl( \frac {a^{(m+5)})} {a^5}  \bigr) =                          
a^{ ( n-3 ) +3 }    +    \bigl( \frac{1} {a^5} \bigr) \bigl( a^{(m+5)} \bigr) =                         
a^n      +   ( a^{-5} )  ( a^{(m+5)} )  =                                                   
a^n     +    a^{ ( m+5 ) -5 }           =     a^n + a^m      $

$ $
One last thing worth mentioning is that you may also factor out common multiples between the terms. Example:

$   a^n + a^m    =     ( a^4 )  ( a^{n-4} )   +   ( a^7 )  ( a^{m-7} )     =                                 a^4 \Bigl(  ( a^{n-4} )    +     (a^3)  ( a^{m-7} )  \Bigr)     $

$ $
Ultimately, while re-writing equations in more complicated forms such as in the manner shown here is not usually useful on its own, doing so $\mathit is$ often useful when working with more complex equations or in writing proofs.
If this response has been insufficient in answering your question, I'd recommend re-visiting the basic rules of exponents, starting with how addition and multiplication are related, and then moving to how multiplication and exponents are related.
Best regards~

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are talking about adding terms which have a constant base and some linear [monic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monic_polynomial) expression in the exponent.

You can do:

$2^{x+2} + 2^{x+2}$

= $2\cdot2^{x+2}$

= $2^1\cdot2^{x+2}$

= $2^{1+(x+2)}$

= $2^{x+3}$

Using these [properties](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/exponent-laws.html).

Comment: The original was not 2^x + 2 i meant 2^(x+2) where (x+2) is the exponent.

Comment: did you mean $2^x + 2^{x+2}$ ?

Comment: No, they both should be 2^(x+2)

Comment: If so your question needs an edit.

Comment: I had it like so but someone edited it wrong

Comment: I changed my answer to match your question.

Comment: the possible answer was $2^{x+4} but i wasnt sure how it got there